# Product of polynomials with negative coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Given $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $|a| > 1$. Let $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial with $g(a)=\pm 1$. Let Let $h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial with $h(a)=\pm p$, a prime. Let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have not all coefficients negative nor positive. Can $g(x)h(x)$ have only positive coefficients? Is there a way to generate such polynomials?

Comment: Product with what?

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121568/on-reducible-polynomials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x^2 - x + 1) (x+1) = x^3 + 1$

If you want strictly positive:

$(4x^2 - x + 1) (2x+1) = 8 x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1$

Comment: thats trueI think I am missing something

Answer (score -1):

Answered here:
by Gerry Myerson https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121568/on-reducible-polynomials

Comment: Well, answered in part. OP would really like an example with $a\gt1$, while my example at MO has $a=-3$. And I didn't address the question of a systematic way to generate examples.

Comment: Ilya Bogdanov has now posted an example there with $a=2$ (and degree $16$), and some details on how to go about finding such things.